# QGIS 3 and Python : How to draw a circle with radius and center

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, circle

I read how to draw a Polyline, but I did not find anything to draw a Circle with radius at a defined position (centre)

```
#Drawing Polyline
polyline = QgsRubberBand(canvas, False)  # False = not a polygon
points =[QgsPoint(-124,48), QgsPoint(-124,51 ), QgsPoint(-120,51),QgsPoint(-120,48)]
polyline.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(points), None)
polyline.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
polyline.setWidth(3)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a buffer around a point coordinate?

Comment: Sorry but "what is a buffer ?" I need a circle on canvas..